# CSS3 : how to get a 5px wide thick horizontal line

Tags: css

I tried the following code css3 style for 5 px wide horizontal line

```
<hr style=" border: solid 1px red;padding-top:10px; margin:25px auto 15px auto;clear:both" />
```

but I am getting 5px wide red rectangle.

Please advise me with a proper CSS3 style code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as the element has the right width, a simple:

```
border-bottom:5px solid red;
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: 2018 -> Then border-top:5px solid red; should be defined as well - true for Firefox v50+

Answer (score 4):

You should use width and height properties instead of border:

```
width: 5px;
height: 1px;
color: red;
```

http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html

Comment: I tried the following                                                        <hr style="width5px;height:1px;color: red;padding-top:10px; margin:25px auto 15px auto;clear:both" /> I didnt get the 5px hr line.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "border-width" property and set it to 5px.
`<hr style="border-width: 5px !important;">`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the top-padding, and use the border-bottom suggested above... http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLfJ/

Comment: You should put your presentation in a separate CSS file, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

My CSS for HR Line Styling;

```
.line_height      { height:4px;                                 }
.line_width       { width:100%;                                 } 
.line_hcenter     { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;      }
.line_vcenter     { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;      }
.line_color       { color:black;                                }
.line_bgcolor     { background-color:black;                     }   
.line_bordercolor { border-top: solid black; border-bottom: solid black; }
```

Add these classes to the hr tag.

All three color ( color , bgcolor, bordercolor ) classes are needed to get a solid colored line across.

Classes .color and .bgcolor needed for browser cross compatibility or else you just get double lines.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use any other thing after border property just make 5px instead of 1 px in border.
I.e

Comment: Be more specific with your answer, Read the SO guidelines before posting.